# Use of $* in shell scripts

Tags: bash, shell

I have a very simple script where I assign variables based on text (any email) piped into a script. Whichever way round I put the first 2 statements only the first one works. Both the expressions in the brackets work independently from the CLI.

```
Var1=$(grep 'Message-ID: <' $* | awk -F: '{print $2}' | tr -d "<> " )
Var2=$(grep 'Subject: ' $* | awk -F: '{print $2}' )

## only Var1 works

Var2=$(grep 'Subject: ' $* | awk -F: '{print $2}' )
Var1=$(grep 'Message-ID: <' $* | awk -F: '{print $2}' | tr -d "<> " )

## only Var2 works
```

I think there is something fundamental I am missing about the
$* expression. Have not been able to find clarity in any of the bash documentation.

Beginner help gratefully recieved.

Comment: What does `$*` expand to? If it's empty, the first subshell is going to consume your script's stdin, while the second one will be left with an empty input.

Comment: This is indeed what seems to happen. Why doesn't the value of $* persist?

Comment: I should have read up to the part where you said you didn't know what it did... it's supposed to expand to the parameters of your script, so if you call `script file1 file2 file3` you'd grep over these 3 files. If you call `otherscript | script` though you're facing the problem I've described above, where the output of `otherscript` is consumed by the first grep, which reads from stdin since it wasn't given a file parameter (`$*` expands to nothing).

Comment: So I see from what you have said that what happens is entirely expected. Would it work to assign the value of $* (the text of the email that is piped in) to another variable within the script and then grep that?

Comment: The text of the email that is piped in isn't accessible through `$*` (which is empty unless you call the script with arguments), it's accessible through the script's standard input. You can store it into a variable by using `var=$(cat)` (because `cat` also reads stdin by default, just as grep, and will simply output it)

Comment: in the manual : https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html#Special-Parameters

Comment: What leaves you to believe that the difference between your two statements is related to `$*`? If you want to see what the shell is *actually* doing, by the way, running `set -x` is an appropriate way to do it.

Comment: As it is, though, we aren't provided an actual [mcve] with a specific, reproducible bug. We have to guess at your filenames and the contents you're trying to match, which isn't conducive to providing a narrow, specific, canonical, and demonstrably-correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Initial Context: On `$@` and `$*`

Both of these *refer to your script's own arguments*. Thus, the expectation is that your script itself will be passed with one or more filenames, and that these files are what should be searched to find email headers.

However, `$*` does this in a way that is completely unsuitable for the purpose at hand; only `"$@"` should be used.

---

#### On Using `$*` To Expand To Filenames

Using `$*` to expand to a list of filenames is **always** buggy, and should **never** be done. It operates as follows:

- Items on your script's argument list are concatenated together into a single string, separated by the first character in `$IFS` (by default, a space).
- That string is split on *all* characters in IFS -- the spaces added by the concatenation are split back out, and spaces between the arguments are *also* broken on to get a list of individual words.
- Each of those words is processed as a glob expression, replacing (for example) a word of `*` with a list of files in the current directory.

If you want to pass your script's argument list through to `grep`, use `"$@"`. **Never** use `$*` except in a context where you explicitly want to concatenate together your arguments into a single string.

---

#### On Extracting Headers From Email

You can extract the message-id from an email using only `awk` as follows (split into multiple lines for clarity):

```
messageId=$(awk -F: '
$1 == "Message-Id" {                 # Match fields where the first field is message-id
  gsub("^[[:space:]]*[<]", "", $2);  # Remove space and < from the beginning (only!)
  gsub("[>]$", "", $2);              # Remove > from the end
  print $2;                          # Print result
  exit(0);                           # exit to avoid more spurious matches later
}' "$@" </dev/null)
```

The subject is even easier, and the below works correctly with subjects with colons in them (which anything relying on `awk -F:` *would not*):

```
subject=$(awk '/^Subject:/ { gsub("^Subject:[[:space:]]+", ""); print $0 }' "$@" </dev/null)
```

Using `</dev/null` ensures that we don't hang even if `"$@"` is empty (and thus there *are* no arguments).